# unable to runt jupyter notebook via ipkernel in vs code using python 3.11.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I upgraded to pytohn 3.11 but when i try to run jupyter notebook in local python environment, It throws an error.
I upgraded pip and setuptools, vs code extensions, microsoft c++ distros but still the probelm persist. I tried to follow the error meg thrown and ran the msg in cmd/admin then i get the other error message. I posted the issue in official vs code and ipkernel github, but till date no one has been able to solve this issue even though ipkernel now officially supports python 3.11.

Link to the github post:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11820
https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/1011

Attached are teh two error messages that i get everytime.
Somebody please help. THank You.
[image]

I upgraded to Python 3.11 and tried running jupyter notebook cell in local python environment but it throws and error.